# Fourier transform help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Find the Fourier tranform of  $f(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$

In a previous question when I found the Fourier transform of $f(x) =e^{-x^2}$, I used the formulas $F(f')=i\omega F$ and $F(xf)=iF'$. Will they be helpful in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying the formula $\widehat{(xf)}(\omega)=i\frac{d}{d\omega}\widehat{f}(\omega)$ *twice*...

Comment: Thankyou @anon .. I will try to do it

Answer (score 1):

Hint: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships) should be very helpful for this :

- look at the top of the table and find your definition of Fourier transform
- search the useful formula : $x^n f(x)$ here
- apply to $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

Fine continuation,

Comment: Thankyou @Raymond Manzoni that was helpful